# ProGuard unexpected behavior

Tags: java, android, obfuscation

I have an Android project in which I'm using progaurd to obfuscate and shirnk the code.

```
    ...

android {
    defaultConfig {
...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
...

    }
    compileOptions {
...
    }
}

dependencies {
...
}
...
```

I have some custom rules in the progaurd-pro file to ignore model files to what they are. It ignore all the model files in the package but it doesn't ignore one specific file.

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class my.domain.models.** { *; }
```

## What I have tried

I moved the all models to different module still no difference
that file isn't being ignored

Comment: Is that file used on run time or using reflection? you can define exact class name in pro guard rules to keep it.

Comment: @TheAnkush what do mean ? please write some code

Comment: and i have tried what u say
hradcoding the name of the class instead of using wild cards

Comment: but it doesn't work that way as well

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out at my own after getting a hint from @TheAnkush 's comment

actually i m **referring those variables from outside the class** referring those variables from outside the class i.e i have kept those variables public so when pro guard parses those file from which it refers those variables directly so it changes these variable and hence these files are altered even after using the right code